# QML prevent ListView delegate to update all the time

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I'm relatively new to QML/QtQuick and still learning. I have a little performane issue with a very small private project. I just tryed to implement a filter function to my ListView, because >15.000 objects are a lot to search manually. I just want to update the ListView when I finished the editing of my search field or pressing "return". But instead it's refreshing every time I insert or delete a character from this textfield which needs sometimes a few seconds.

Anyone have an idea how to prevent the list to be refreshed permanently or reducing theese performance issues?

Thanks a lot

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.XmlListModel 2.12
import Anime_initialiser  1.0
import "."

Page {
    TextField{
        id: searchField
        width: parent.width
        z: 1
        /*onEditingFinished: {
            XL.animeListModel.reload()
        }*/
    }
    ListView {
        z: 0
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar { active: true }
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        model: XL.animeListModel
        y: searchField.height
        Anime_initialiser {
            id: initialiser
            onShowAnimeDetails: {
                xmlDataString = xmlString
                swipeView.currentIndex = swipeView.currentIndex+1
            }
        }
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            visible: {
                if (searchField.length > 0)
                    return (main_title.toLowerCase().match(searchField.text.toLowerCase()) || de_title.toLowerCase().match(searchField.text.toLowerCase())) ? true : false
                else
                    return true
            }
            height:  visible ? Button.height : 0
            width: parent ? parent.width : 0
            Button {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    anime_id = aid
                    initialiser.buttonClicked(anime_id)
                }
                Text {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height
                    font.pointSize: 100
                    minimumPointSize: 12
                    fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
                    text: aid + ": " + main_title + (de_title ? "\nDE: " + de_title : "")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than toggling the visible flag of all of your delegates, you should use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). The idea is that the proxy model would use your `XL.animeListModel` as a source model, and then you can give the proxy a regular expression telling it which ones to filter out. Depending on how you want it to filter, you could just call `setFilterRole()` to tell it which property to compare against your regex, or you could do a custom filter by overriding the `filterAcceptsRow()` function.

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to use a proxy, you can still prevent the constant updates by not binding on the `visible` property directly to the search field. You were on the right track with your `onEditingFinished` code. You could create a separate text string that just holds the completed search text.

```
property string searchText: ""
```

Then update that string when you are done typing your search text.

```
onEditingFinished: {
    searchText = searchField.text.toLowerCase();
}
```

And finally, bind your `visible` property to this new string.

```
            visible: {
                if (searchText.length > 0)
                    return (main_title.toLowerCase().match(searchText) || de_title.toLowerCase().match(searchText)) ? true : false
                else
                    return true
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw several posts inlcuding "QSortFilterProxyModel" but I thought I can get aroung it this way. Even then, I would really like to understand why QML is doing this. I thought the list will get rendered once and won't be updated without a direct call. Do you (or anyone else) know and can explain me why this happenes?

Comment: You have bound the delegate's `visible` property to the searchField.text. Every time that text changes, it will reevaluate `visible`. I can add an edit to my answer to show you how to get around that.

Comment: If you have the time and like to do that, it would be really nice but you don't have to. It would be just to understand QML a little bit more. But even if it's just a private project, I will try to do it the clean way with QSortFilter. You helped me alot so far, thanks.